# How does Lavinia, Azorius Renegade interact with K'rrik, Son of Yawgmoth?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So my question is how would [Lavinia, Azorius Renegade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lavinia%2C%20Azorius%20Renegade) interact with [K'rrik, Son of Yawgmoth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=K%27rrik%2C%20Son%20of%20Yawgmoth) if someone used K'rrik's abilities to just pay the life to cast a spell instead of paying mana? e.g. casting [Dauthi Voidwalker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dauthi%20Voidwalker) while Lavinia is out.

Answer (score 7):

**If only life was paid to cast a spell, Lavinia will counter it.**

*Magic* is a literal game. What is written on the card is exactly what the card does. If you cast a spell whose mana cost contains only {B} using K'rrik's ability ("For each {B} in a cost, you may pay 2 life rather than pay that mana"), and choose to pay life rather than mana for every one of those {B} symbols, then you didn't spend any mana to cast it. That means Lavinia will trigger and counter the spell.

That said, K'rrik's ability applies to each {B} symbol individually. So in your example of casting Dauthi Voidwalker, if you have even one black mana to spare, you can pay {B} and 2 life and Lavinia won't notice.